Load only low resolution of polygons in Leaflet
Leaflet uses the principle of loading map tiles according to the zoom level, that is, the resolution of the map image depends on the zoom level. Can we apply the same principle to a polygon?
My website main page loads a broad map with several high-resolution polygons, but they take a lot of time to load (around 7 MB, ~2s, which is a lot for a main page). Is there a way to load only a low resolution version of the polygons, and load higher resolution versions according to zoom level, exactly as it's done with the raster tiles?


It's not just question of resolution but also of extent of what is being loaded. Raster tiles are loaded only for what is visible in the map view, but vector layer is loaded in it's entirety regardless of the map view.You could have several version of vector data for different zooms, but if you would zoom in, you would have to load entire detailed vector layer. The only solution is to convert you vector layer data to vector tiles (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_tiles).

Another possible solution would be to ZIP vector data, fetch it in the app, unzip it and then use it for layer.

You might want to have a look at Leaflet.VectorGrid.Slicer.

@TomazicM express/nginx server already sends the data gziped and decompressed by the browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172704/is-gzip-automatically-decompressed-by-browser

@IvanSanchez can you kindly provide some examples for Leaflet

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/#demos

@IvanSanchez I saw it and I implemented here, please see my example, but I still don't get how shall I reduce the amount of data sent from the server to the client. I still need to load the full data. What shall I do?

Leaflet.VectorGrid.Slicer won't reduce traffic between server and client, only efficiency of display once data is fetched from the client. To reduce traffic, you will have to use vector tiles.

@TomazicM are you aware of any plugin for Leaflet for vector tiles to reduce traffic? I tried with geojson-vt (I tried this, see 2nd example), but I still can't get it how should I reduce traffic. Any ideas?

found it https://richorama.github.io/2019/02/05/roll-your-own-vector-tile-service/

As you have found out, it has to be done server side.

I still didn't find the proper client-side plugin to render .pbf vector-tiles for leaflet, still searching :)

See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid. You have to use L.VectorGrid.Protobuf

Backend
I need a Vector tiles server (from here)
const http = require('http')
const geojsonvt = require('geojson-vt')
const vtpbf = require('vt-pbf')
const data = require('./geojson-source-data.json')

// build the tile index from GeoJSON source data
const tileIndex = geojsonvt(data)

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(port)
console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)

// expects urls in the format: /{Z}/{X}/{Y}.pbf
function handleRequest(req, res) {
  const [z, x, y] = req.url
    .replace('.pbf', '')
    .split('/')
    .filter(n => n)
    .map(n => parseInt(n))

  // get the vectors for this tile
  const tile = tileIndex.getTile(z, x, y)

  // if there is no tile data, return an empty response
  if (!tile) {
    res.writeHead(204, { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' })
    return res.end()
  }

  // encode as protobuf
  const buffer = Buffer.from(vtpbf.fromGeojsonVt({ geojsonLayer: tile }))

  // write the buffer to the response stream
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/protobuf',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  })
  res.write(buffer, 'binary')
  res.end(null, 'binary')
}

Frontend
Then on the client side I need to use the plugin Leaflet.VectorGrid and particularly the method L.VectorGrid.Protobuf
Example:
import 'leaflet.vectorgrid/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js'

L.vectorGrid.protobuf('/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf', {
  rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile
}).addTo(map)

